# How to use Device Info Plus library to get the width and height of device in Flutter/Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

I want to get the device's width and height in pixels in my Flame application.  I've been looking at the api website's examples (https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) and trying to put them both together to get the specific information I need, but I keep getting errors.  Is this because of Flame or am I doing something wrong?

I've added the library and updated the yaml file.  I just took some lines of code and put them together and I'm receiving an error when trying to get the device width.

Here is the code:

```
    final deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    final deviceInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.deviceInfo;
    final allInfo = deviceInfo.data;
    final deviceWidth = deviceInfo.displayMetrics.widthPx;
    print("DEVICE INFO");
    print(allInfo);
```

Here is the error:

> error: The getter 'displayMetrics' isn't defined for the type 'BaseDeviceInfo'.

Comment: Have you tried using MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and MediaQuery.of(context).size.width?

Comment: @Shan I haven't.  What does it mean by context?  Can you provide me with a link to the api or something?

Comment: @Shan Upon further research, I don't think MediaQuery will work because it's a Flame game and there is no MaterialApp or WidgetsApp

Comment: Yes you are right, I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `devive_info_plus` to get the size of the screen in Flame, that information already exists on the `FlameGame` class.

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() {
    this.size; // <-- This is the size of the visible game canvas
  }
}
```

You can also access the `size` from a `Component` that is added to the tree.

```dart
class MyComponent extends Component with HasGameReference {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() {
    game.size; // Same as in the FlameGame
  }

  @override
  void onGameResize(Vector2 size) {
    // This lifecycle method is called every time the screen resizes
    // This method exists in all components so for this you don't
    // need the HasGameReference mixin.
  }
}
```

Other sizes that might be of interest:

```dart
game.camera.gameSize;
game.camera.canvasSize;
```

Comment: this.size in the game worked perfectly!  Thank you!